# Edge coloring of a graph $G$ with node degrees divisible by $p$ and number of edges NOT divisible by $p$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with node degrees divisible by $p$ and number of edges not divisible by $p$, show that there exists a coloring (using $p$ colors) of the edges such that for every vertex the number of edges incident with that vertex in any two color classes differ by at most one.

Assume $p \ge 2$.

This is what I've been able to deduce: let $d_1, d_2,...,d_n$ be the degrees of the $n = |V|$ nodes of $G$. Because $p \mid d_1, p \mid d_2,...,p \mid d_n$, we can conclude that $p \mid 2*|E|$. Knowing that $p \nmid |E|$, we further conclude that $2 \mid p$, so $p$ and $d_1, d_2,...,d_n$ must be even. Having deduced this information, I tend to believe that the coloring must be somehow related to the Euler tour of the graph (because $G$ is an Eulerian graph). But I don't know how to continue my reasoning.

Any help will be strongly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "differ by at most one" would in fact imply "do not differ", wouldn't it?

Comment: I believe so. Given a node with degree $d$ and having $p$, each color must appear $d / p$ times. If it does not, then the difference would be at least 2. Is this correct?

Comment: For $p = 2$, I think that I can take the Eulerian tournament and color its edges alternatively with 0s and 1s. But I'm failing to extend this idea for $p \gt 2$.

Comment: The question as worded isn't  correct though: For example, in any 2-coloring of the edges of a 3-cycle($p=2$) there is one vertex that will be incident to 2 edges of the same color, and none of the other color.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. Indeed, let $c_1,\dots,c_p$ be the set of used colors and $v$ be any vertex of $G$. For any color $c_i$ let $k_i$ be a number of edges incident to $v$ colored with a color $c_i$. There exists a number $k$ such that $k=k_i$ or $k=k_i+1$ for each color $i$. Let $r\le p$ be the number of colors $i$ with $k=k_i+1$. Since $r\equiv \sum k_i\equiv \deg v\equiv 0\pmod p$, we have $r=0$ or $r=p$. In both cases all $k_i$’s are equal.